# Django-Import-Export to import CSV, how to work with u'\\ufeff, UTF-8 BOM issue?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

When I'm trying to import CSV file using django-import-export modules gives this error,

> KeyError: u"Column 'id' not found in dataset. Available columns are:
>   [**u'\ufeffid**', u'username', u'name', u'email']"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, 
Changing django-import-export module's encoding in ImportMixin class in import_export/admin.py file,

Change `from_encoding = "utf-8"`to`from_encoding = "utf-8-sig"` as below.

```
class ImportMixin(ImportExportMixinBase):
    """
    Import mixin.
    """

    #: template for change_list view
    change_list_template = 'admin/import_export/change_list_import.html'
    #: template for import view
    import_template_name = 'admin/import_export/import.html'
    #: resource class
    resource_class = None
    #: available import formats
    formats = DEFAULT_FORMATS
    #: import data encoding
    from_encoding = "utf-8-sig"
    skip_admin_log = None
    # storage class for saving temporary files
    tmp_storage_class = None
```